# iptables-allports doesn't work with docker site on port 81

Tags: docker, fail2ban

I have a site running via Docker on port 81. I want to ban users bruteforcing the site.

Here is my config:

```
[mysite]
enabled = true
port = http,https,81
filter = mysite
logpath = /var/log/mysite.log
maxretry = 10
findtime = 3600
bantime = 30
action = iptables-allports
```

And this works somewhat, the user gets banned on SSH and HTTP ports, but not on port 81.

Here's a snippet of my `fail2ban.log`

```
2018-04-27 13:12:48,323 fail2ban.actions        [7817]: NOTICE  [mysite] Ban {MY-IP}
2018-04-27 13:12:48,369 fail2ban.filter         [7817]: INFO    [mysite] Found {MY-IP}
2018-04-27 13:12:48,460 fail2ban.filter         [7817]: INFO    [mysite] Found {MY-IP}
2018-04-27 13:12:48,536 fail2ban.filter         [7817]: INFO    [mysite] Found {MY-IP}
2018-04-27 13:12:48,549 fail2ban.actions        [7817]: NOTICE  [mysite] {MY-IP} already banned
2018-04-27 13:12:48,616 fail2ban.filter         [7817]: INFO    [mysite] Found {MY-IP}
2018-04-27 13:12:48,699 fail2ban.filter         [7817]: INFO    [mysite] Found {MY-IP}
```

As you can see, after I've been banned I still have access on port 81.

Answer (score 0):

look at your iptables input chain, docker might be adding forwarding rules before the fail2ban rules.